# Is there a LaTeX command to make text all lower caps?

Tags: latex, macros

Hey, I am trying to write a command to print todays date on the front page of a report using the textsc command, but the today date capitalize December.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you have an answer but my question would be, why?  As far as I know, in English, you need the capital letter (and not in French as too many unfortunately do).

Comment: I presume the question should say "lower case", not "lower caps". Lower caps is a style/font issue, and it doesn't seem to be what you're asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `\MakeLowercase` macro or `\MakeTextLowercase` from the [textcase](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/textcase/) package. See [this page](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=casechange) in the UK TeX FAQ for more info.